# how to set the media features in media queries, like width is in between two pixels like 300px - 400px?

Tags: css, media-queries

In the media queries

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}
```

This will execute when the screen's min-width is 300px.
If i want to execute the code when the width is inbetween the 300px - 500px how i will write the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Its pretty simple**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 359px) and (min-width: 240px){

    .detail_image{height:160px; width:280px;}
    .video_cntrl{height:160px; width:auto;}
}
```

I highly suggest you to use aspect ratio based resolution it will rectify your worries.

please [view](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_resolution) it.

Answer (score 1):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 500px)
{
    body {
            background-color: lightblue;
         }
}
```